# JQuery - bind() again when count is reset

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my game I want to make sure the start button is only clicked once each time it appears to stop it loading the function more than once.

I have written some code that counts the clicks and unbinds if the count is greater than zero.

```
var oneClick = 0;
$(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", function () {
    oneClick++;
        if (oneClick > 0) {
        $(this).unbind("click");
    }
        newGame();
});
```

This works fine but I need a way to bind it again ready for the next time it appears (When the restart-btn is clicked) so I have written this to reset the count.

```
$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    resetGame();
    oneClick = 0;

});
```

For some reason this doesn't do the job and I am looking to SO for a soloution

Comment: If you use the newest jQuery you need to change [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 2):

You're not binding again but just changing oneClick, which isn't even tested as the event handler to `$(".start-btn-wrapper")` isn't binded anymore.

But instead of unbinding/rebinding, which is costly, why not just test `oneClick` :

```
$(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", function () {
    if (oneClick++ > 0) return;
    newGame();
}
```

Note that if you just need two states, a boolean would be clearer :

```
var clickable = true;
$(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", function () {
    if (!clickable) return;
    newGame();
    clickable = false;
}
$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    resetGame();
    clickable = true;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a built in method for exactly this use. It is [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

So all you have to do is

```
$(".start-btn-wrapper").one('click',newGame);
```

and for the restart

```
$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    resetGame();
    $(".start-btn-wrapper").one('click',newGame);
});
```

Comment: Simple!! +1 Thanks!! @Gaby aka G. Petrioli

Answer (score 0):

simple

```
var oneClick = 0;
$(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", function () {

        if (oneClick > 0) {
        return false;
    }
        oneClick++;
        newGame();
});

$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    resetGame();
    oneClick = 0;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var oneClick = 0;

function clickHandler() {
    oneClick++;
        if (oneClick > 0) {
        $(".start-btn-wrapper").unbind("click");
    }
        newGame();
}

$(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", clickHandler);

$(".restart-btn").click(function () {
    resetGame();
    oneClick = 0;

    $(".start-btn-wrapper").bind("click", clickHandler);
});
```